# How to delete a former admin user from SBS2011?

Tags: windows-domain, windows-sbs, domain-security

I am trying to remove a former admin user from our SBS 2011 domain. When trying to delete it from the [SBS 2011 Standard Console](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc546041(v=ws.11).aspx) I get "Access denied".

I've read op on this case on a [number](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/28148755/Cannot-remove-an-account-from-an-SBS.html) of [sites](http://www.support42.co.uk/it-support-sussex/kb.php?id=196). A popular suggestion seems to be to reset the AdminCount value on the user's property via ADSIedit.

I did this, however I still can't remove the user from the domain.

Also, I tried to delete it with other user accounts, also by giving administrator user full permissions to it. I tried to remove the user from the Active Directory manager console, no dice. The error message in I get when trying to delete the user from the AD manager is: "You are not authorized to delete  or this object is secured against accidental removal"

What else can I try to remove this former admin account?

**Edit:** This question is unique from the mentioned duplicate, because this is SBS2011/Server 2008 with a protected user account. The answer in the mentioned duplicate describes how to remove a local user account on windows 10. This question intends to remove an SBS 2011 domain administrator account.

Comment: By console I mean the SBS 2011 Standard Console: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc546041(v=ws.11).aspx

Comment: I tried to delete it with other user accounts, also by giving administrator user full permissions to it, I tried to remove the user from the Active Directory manager console, no dice. The error message in I get when trying to delete the user from the AD manager is: "You are not authorized to delete <CN=blabla name> or this object is secured against accidental removal"

Comment: Done. Could one please explain why this question needs closing? I'll update the question again if nescessary.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I delete user directory after deleting user?](http://superuser.com/questions/1124883/can-i-delete-user-directory-after-deleting-user)

Comment: I don't see why that is a duplicate of my question. This is windows server 2008 with a protected user account. It doesn't just leave the user folder there, but the entire account.

Comment: @Ramhound, do you care to answer the question?

Comment: My answer would be the answe submitted to the duplicate, I would provide more detai obviously, but I don't have any other solution.  I am more then familar with Windows Server 2008+, so no need, to mention anything releated to my knowlege because you disagree

Comment: Ok. Thx for your help. I've updated the question for clarification. I hope someone else can answer the question now.

Comment: [Windows 2008 - Remove Windows User Remotely](http://serverfault.com/questions/555454/windows-2008-remove-windows-user-remotely)

Comment: `When trying to delete it from the console I get "Access denied"` does not tell us what you tried.  This a built-in account or an account that exists on the Active Domain itself.

Comment: It is an account that exists only on the Active Domain. The Console is what you use on SBS2011 to manage, create and delete domain users with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by giving the local server Administrator user full control over the user's object in Active Directory - Users and Computers.

In order to do this, go to:

> Active Directory - Users and Computers => domain.local => MyBusiness => Users => SBSUsers.

Then rightclick on your user, select properties => Select the "Security" tab. Then add the Administrator user to the list of users and groups, and give it full control (make sure all checkboxes are checked).

Also, when you have this problem then you need to verify if the setting "Prevent this object from accidental deletion" is unchecked on the Object tab of the same window.